# Erasing all non-numbers on a string using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

I have a task to check a string if it contains non-numbers in it and then remove those.

I tried this code below and it doesn't work. Could someone point out what's wrong with my code?

```
recursiveNAN(string num, int pos)
    {
        char tmp=num[pos];
        if(pos<0)
        {
            this->create(); //allocates memory for the new number
            *this->num = stoi(num); //translate string to number
        }
        if (isdigit(tmp)&&pos>=0)
        {
            this->recursiveNAN(num, pos-1); 
        }
        else if (!isdigit(tmp) && pos>=0)
        {

            num.erase(pos,1);
            this->recursiveNAN(num,pos-1); 
        }
    }
```

It doesn't say any errors while compiling but it does while debugging.

Comment: Compiler just makes sure the code is syntactically correct. For the most part, you're on your own when it comes to logic. You should add to the question a [mcve] and definitely add what's happening and what you want to happen instead.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why this must be done recursively? My naïve approach of scanning/patching/cleaning a string would be iteratively as long as no "stack-machine" approach is needed.

Comment: cant you use regex? remove all things that are not digits then turn the string to int

Comment: No need for regex:  `num.erase(std::remove_if(num.begin(), num.end(), [](char c){return !::isdigit(c);}), num.end());`

Comment: Never use `std::isdigit` with a plain `char` argument like that - always convert to `unsigned char` before allowing it to be promoted to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be quickly done using regex:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>


int main()
{
    std::string s("14scds3vkj12");
    std::regex r("\\D+");
    std::cout<<std::stoi(std::regex_replace(s,r,""));
}
```

outputs:

```
14312
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to use recursion

Comment: @JeremyPalad so what exactly do you want to achieve?